# Apache Spark: Transforming large DataFrame efficiently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a 1GB csv file that I load using the DataFrame API. I also implemented a custom `Transformer` that prepares the data so it can be processed by an `Estimator`.

There are some different operations that the `transform` method is doing:

- Casting columns.
- Filtering rows.
- Dropping columns.
- Creating new columns applying a function over other columns.

I'm concerned about the memory usage during this process. What happens if, after each transformation, I store the result in a variable? For example (simplified):

```
override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {

    val df = dataset.withColumn("DayOfWeek", $"DayOfWeek".cast("int"))

    val df2 = df1.filter($"Diverted" === 0)

    val df3 = df2.drop(forbiddenVariables: _*)

    val df4 = df3.withColumn("DepHour", hourExtractorUdf($"DepTime"))

    val df5 = df4.select($"*", concat($"Origin", lit("-"), $"Dest").as("Route"))

    df5

}
```

Let's say I'm doing that for logging purpose between one transformation and another.

Ok. Second option. What if I use a `var` instead of a `val`?

```
override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {

    var df = dataset.withColumn("DayOfWeek", $"DayOfWeek".cast("int"))

    df = df.filter($"Diverted" === 0)

    df = df.drop(forbiddenVariables: _*)

    df = df.withColumn("DepHour", hourExtractorUdf($"DepTime"))

    df = df.select($"*", concat($"Origin", lit("-"), $"Dest").as("Route"))

    df

}
```

I suppose that now I don't have 5 DataFrames loaded in memory during all the process. Right?

And finally, what about the next option, is it more memory-efficient?

```
override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {

    dataset.withColumn("DayOfWeek", $"DayOfWeek".cast("int"))
      .filter($"Diverted" === 0)
      .drop(forbiddenVariables: _*)
      .withColumn("DepHour", hourExtractorUdf($"DepTime"))
      .select($"*", concat($"Origin", lit("-"), $"Dest").as("Route"))

}
```

I'm supposing, of course, that there is no option that is more computationally expensive than the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All versions of your code are equivalent since they produce identical dataframes at the end and perform no side effects.  There seems to be some fundamental misunderstanding of how spark works.  DataFrames contain no data.   All they are is an execution plan.

In learning spark often we discuss the distinction between "transformations" and "actions".

Transformations modify data, these are things like `filter`, `select`, `drop` and any other method that modifies your dataframe.  "transformations" do zero work, they just build up the execution plan.

Actions on the other hand actually perform some visible effect.  These are things like saving to a file, collecting results to the driver, or consuming your data with foreach.  Only when an action is called does your dataframe get evaluated and the transformations run.

1GB of data is also very small, if that's all you have perhaps reconsider if you really need to use spark.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, in the first case, I have variables that references previous states of the dataset, right? (i.e., df and df2 point to different DataFrames) I know that the correct way to save state is "caching", but I want to know what happens when I use `val`.

Comment: @fedigazon Those DataFrames disappear as soon as the method returns and they are never evaluated (ie. you never call an action on them).  Since you never use those dataframes it makes no difference if you store them in a variable or not.  `val` also makes no difference, it doesn't do anything special to the value,  it just prevents the variable frombeing reassigned.  Again, DataFrames contain zero data, they are just an execution plan to be evaluated when you call an action.